# How to prevent ListView checkbox click through

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView and I have set CheckBoxes = true. 
The Problem is that when I click on the checkboxes the click event goes to the window behind my form i.e. click through occurs and my window is minimized. It happens only near the borders of the checkboxes, rest of the place (the empty space) it doesn't happen.

Please check snapshots here:

The listView checkboxes

[image]

the background image (actually an advert)

[image: image2]

you can see the colors which are appearing around checkboxes borders and the background window/image.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

**EDIT:**

This is the code that is run in OnLoad in parent form of this form.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    this.Opacity = 0;
    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(244, 244, 244);
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(244, 244, 244);
    oWidth = this.Width;
    btw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(btw_DoWork);
    btw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(btw_ProgressChanged);
    btw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(btw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    btw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    //this.TopMost = true;
    this.TopMost = false;



}
```

There is a .PNG as BackgroundImage of this form (which is of Gray color.)

Comment: I assume you have a background image. Does it have tranparency in it?   Also: What is the BackColor of the form? And: Are you using a region? How is it created?

Comment: Yes I have BackgroundImage, a .png image and the BackColor of the form is Gray.

Comment: Png images can have tranparency. I assume that what Nimesh refers to a the form's border is actually a part of the image. Do you agree that the desktop is bleeding through the vertical strip there too?

Comment: Yes same thing happens there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the problem is in the form transparency key color of your windows form. the checkbox area backcolor and transparency key color are same. So, your checkbox is transparent. When you are click on checkbox the click goes on the background form. Use different transparency color rather then white or smoke white. for example green or blue.

**EDITED:**

if you can see here your background image is displaying through the front form border.

[image]   **Side By Side**   [image]

As per msdn

When the TransparencyKey property is assigned a Color, the areas of the form that have the same BackColor will be displayed transparently. Any mouse actions, such as the click of the mouse, that are performed on the transparent areas of the form will be transferred to the windows below the transparent area. For example, if the client region of a form is made transparent, clicking the mouse on that area would send the event notification of the click to any window that is below it. If the color assigned to the TransparencyKey property is the same as any controls on the form, they also will be displayed transparently. For example, if you have a Button control on a form that has its TransparencyKey property set to SystemColors.Control, the control will be displayed transparently unless the BackColor property of the Button control is changed to a different color.

Comment: Tried changing TransparencyKey of the form in which this ListView is, to Green, but it didn't help.

Comment: how did you make this form in irregular shape(Mobile Shape)?

Comment: That I'm not sure I have not developed it, but there is a backgroundImage in the form of Gray color. which is a .png

Comment: But, there is something wrongly codded that creating form border and checkboxes transperent.

Comment: I found something in OnLoad method of its parent form. May be that is how it is done. Please check EDIT.

Comment: change `Color.FromArgb(244, 244, 244);` to `Color.Green` from the both line. Backcolor and TransparencyKey

Comment: That worked. Thanks. But can you please explain what is the issue here?